# 0% Code Coverage of Blazor component source file included in my SonarQube report

Tags: sonarqube, blazor, sonarqube-scan

I have a Blazor app with many components. Running unit test for those components on Visual Studio gives me the fully coverage report.
As scanning code with SonarQube using MSBuild Scanner, my unit test command is:

```
dotnet test .\Tests\App.Test.csproj /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover --logger trx
```

yet there’s 0% of Blazor code coverage in my SonarQube Web Report .

My Scanner commands:

```
 dotnet "C:\Program Files\sonar-scanner\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll" begin /k:"My-Project" /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="Tests\coverage.opencover.xml"

dotnet build

dotnet "C:\Program Files\sonar-scanner\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll" end
```

I am wondering if there’s any missing item in my config file SonarQube.Analysis.xml.

Comment: Did you find any alternative?

Comment: @SergiyMatvienko I use code behind .cs file to workaround this issue : put C# code into a separate partial class in `{blazor-component-name}.razor.cs` ex here : https://github.com/Aguafrommars/TheIdServer/tree/master/src/BlazorApp/Aguacongas.TheIdServer.BlazorApp.Pages.Api  
It's not perfect I admit

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately SonarQube doesn't analyze Blazor files (yet). So it doesn't process the result of your coverage report.